# Knockout bind after select render

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

So I have a Select that has its options from a computed. I want to select a default every time the selects options change.

I have tried several different ways of doing it:

- subscribe to list - is called before list has returned so changes the value of the observable alright but it dosnt render right because the list changes AFTER.
- afterRender - Does not work with this type of binding.
- OptionsafterRender - works, as in the fiddle below, HOWEVER its called for every individual item rather then just once on the whole render so strikes me as the Wrong Way to do this.

```js
var rawData = [{
  Type: "1",
  Color: "Blue",
  Name: "Blue Car"
}, {
  Type: "2",
  Color: "Blue",
  Name: "Blue House"
}, {
  Type: "1",
  Color: "Red",
  Name: "Red Car"
}, {
  Type: "2",
  Color: "Red",
  Name: "Red House"
}];
var viewModel = {
  FirstSelectedOption: ko.observable(),
  SecondSelectOptions: null,
  SecondSelectedOption: ko.observable(),
  Load: function() {
    var self = viewModel;
    self.SecondSelectOptions = ko.computed(function() {
      var selected = self.FirstSelectedOption();
      var returnValue = new Array({
        Type: "*",
        Color: "All",
        Name: "All"
      });
      var filteredlist = ko.utils.arrayFilter(rawData, function(item) {
        return item.Type == selected;
      });
      returnValue = returnValue.concat(filteredlist);
      return returnValue;
    }, self);
    self.SecondSelectedOption.SetDefault = function() {
      // we want the default to always be blue instead 'all', blue might not be the last option
      var self = viewModel;
      var defaultoption = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.SecondSelectOptions(), function(item) {
        return item.Color == "Blue";
      });
      self.SecondSelectedOption(defaultoption);
    };
  }

};

viewModel.Load();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="value: FirstSelectedOption">
  <option value="1">Car</option>
  <option value="2">House</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select data-bind="options: SecondSelectOptions, 
                   optionsText: 'Name',                               
                   value: SecondSelectedOption,
                   optionsAfterRender: SecondSelectedOption.SetDefault"></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dt627rkp/

The only way I can think off off the top of my head is a custom binding...and im not even sure that would really be possible without reimplemnting the entire options binding.
I can't be the first one to want this, is there a best practice/way that I'm missing?

Comment: You could create 2 Selects for the color selectors.  And then show/hide depending on which selection is made in the car/house selector...

Comment: Hmm thats crazy enough to work...I'm not sure I like it however because the data is actually dynamically loaded and theres a lot of it so I'd have to dynamically add them to the dom when the other options on the first selector are selected, but not impossible. Obviously the snipet isnt my actual code its WAY simplified.Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `optionsAfterRender` callback passes 2 parameters: option (element), and item (data bound to the option). The callback already loops over the options, so no need to reiterate:

```
self.SecondSelectedOption.SetDefault = function (option, item) {
   var self = viewModel;
   if (item.Color === 'Blue')
       self.SecondSelectedOption(item);
};
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/dt627rkp/1/)
Ref: [from the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#note-2-post-processing-the-generated-options)

EDIT: That being said, if you don't want the options to re-evaluate every time, 
you could also simply bind the `change` event with the `setDefault` method on the first `<select>`. If I were faced with this code 'issue', I would probably preprocess the data into separate arrays, like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/dt627rkp/2/)

Comment: Bah why didn't I think of that. Still means it gets called every time an item is added to the list which can be a lot with the larger lists but you've eliminated the loop at least so I'm not as concerned with performance. And I dont think its possible to do any better without rewriting the whole thing or a big custom binding.Thanx!

Comment: @Madoc if you want you can also preprocess the data into arrays. If you have the possibility I would separate the color and property type (which is actually a 'computed' property) and make it just a little more semantic, see  my edit.

Comment: @Tybiltz I will try the change event tomorrow not sure if it will fire in the right order, easily tested. I can't split the data like that, well I can but it would cause a lot more problems then it would solve because the real data is way more complicated, used in more places and even more interconnected then this example shows.  I wrote the fiddle from scratch as the simplest possible piece that would reflect what I wanted to do. It has a lot of layers stripped out. There's a lot of things in there that I wouldn't do that way if the data was actually as simple as the example. But thank you!